# Problem with changing button hover state in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am struggling with creating a custom hover for my button in wordpress. I am tying to create something like this:

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/kylehyams/details/gWPRaq)

Here is the effect in css, I am trying to achieve:

```
.button-solid:before {
    content: "";
    background: #FF0033;
    border: solid 2px #FF0033;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}


.container .button-solid:hover:before {
    background: #b30024;
    border-color: #b30024; }
```

So, I add a custom class to my button object and in dev tools, it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code in theme customize:

```
.et_pb_button_module_wrapper .et_pb_button:before {
    content: "";
    background: #FF0033;
    border: solid 2px #FF0033;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
.et_pb_button_0_wrapper:hover:before {
    background: #b30024;
    border-color: #b30024;
}
```

But IT doesn't want to change the color or create a **before** pseudoclass. In dev tools, I see it is visible but cannot apply.

[image]

On the other hand when I change my classes only to **et_pb_button_module_wrapper** it works fine but change whole div which I don't want to.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targeting the entire wrapper for the hover state.

Surely you want to be targeting the button with the hover state which then updates the previous :before background and border css.

```css
.et_pb_button {
    position: relative;
}

.et_pb_button:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #FF0033;
    border: solid 2px #FF0033;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

.et_pb_button:hover:before {
    background: #b30024;
    border-color: #b30024;
}
```

If you want the shine effect as per the [codepen example](https://codepen.io/kylehyams/pen/gWPRaq), then you will need to also add this too...

```css
.et_pb_button:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border: solid 2px #f3f3f3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    transform: skewX(-30deg);
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

.et_pb_button:hover:after {
    left: 79%;
    -webkit-animation-name: shine;
    animation-name: shine;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 200ms;
    animation-duration: 200ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```